# Is it possible to copy red channel to alpha channel in gimp?

Tags: gimp

Is there a way to do it without sacrifices?

Comment: http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/22723636.jpg

Comment: Why use gimp at all? There are better suited programs for this.

Comment: The only program which has easy way to do this is Nuke. Also, with some hard dances it is possible in paintnet. But one does not simply install paintnet on mac.

Comment: It seems that "Colors -> Color To Alpha" should do the trick if you set the color to ff0000.

Comment: I will answer so as to get credit, and not have it in the unanswered tab. :)

Comment: GIMP is great, but I haven't found anything that can grasp the simple concept of alpha as just another channel. Everything I can do with rgb I should be able to do with alpha. Photoshop is disgusting for that and gimp doesn't make it easy.

Answer (score 10):

This does the job well:

Colors->Components->Decompose

- Set Color Model to RGBA
- Uncheck "Decompose to layers" - my personal preference
- OK

Colors->Components->Recompose

Swap the RED and ALPHA channels

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that "Colors -> Color To Alpha" should do the trick if you set the color to ff0000.